# Panel Data, Fixed Effects regression

Tags: panel-data, fixed-effects-model, robust-standard-error

I have a question about the fixed effects model.

I have 25 manufacturing sectors for a 12 year period (balanced panel data set) and I try to find out the effect of each sector's investment expenditure on the ratio of skilled/ unskilled workers for each sector, so my regression model is:

S/U= f(real investment expenditure)

among other things. Because I'm interested in capturing the effect of investment on S/U for different sectors individually, I created dummy variables for each sector and interacted them with investment expenditures of each sector. When I run that regression with fixed effects, investment appears to be a significant factor for determining skill ratio only for 2 sectors. However, when I run the regression with fe, vce (robust), the relationship seems significant for almost all sectors.

I'm wondering how this is possible.

Comment: It’s not clear to me exactly what you’re doing in the two cases you’re comparing.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question and the Stata FAQ quoted above, note that when you use `vce(robust)` in `[xtreg, fe]`, Stata interprets this as `[xtreg, fe vce(cluster)]`.

If you have a negative correlation in either the regressor of interest or the errors within the cluster, you can have such effect.

Please look at this [Stata FAQ](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/standard-errors-and-vce-cluster-option/)
or  [Cameron & Miller, 2015](http://cameron.econ.ucdavis.edu/research/Cameron_Miller_JHR_2015_February.pdf) , p17.

Answer (score -1):

I think your question is more suitable to model in a generalized linear mixed model with a random and slope model specification, ie.

> $$ \log\left(\frac{S}{U}\right)\sim   1+ \text{investment} + (1+\text{investment} | \text{sector}),$$

It's a more powerful method that also take into account the random effect of the sectors